# How to easily save entries of a ComboBox for next program start?

Tags: c#, combobox

I use the below line of code in my program. I get the value through textBox3.Text and then append it to the comboBox that already has two values.

```
comboBox2.Items.Add(textBox3.Text);
```

It is adding the value to the application at run-time. But, once I close the application and run the application again, the newly added value is not featuring in the drop down menu.

How to save the value to the comboBox2 collections. All the manuals/posts, are pointing to only Add method to add values to the items. Am I missing something....

Comment: Serialize the items when closing the app, deserialize at open and add the items to the combobox2?

Comment: If the items are simple then you might consider saving it in a textfile separated by new lines.

Comment: You open your application and type some data in textbox. Then data is shown at combobox and you do not save data. Then you close the application. Your entered data is lost. You do not instruct your computer to save data. Where does computer take data if you run your program at the second time?)

Comment: Have a look at [User settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx) if you want to persist data that you enter at your application at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the app, you can save your ComboBox items via serialization:

First, go ahead and create any class and decorate it with the Serializable attribute. Next, add a field of type `List<string>` and a blank constructor to it like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserData //You can name this anything you like.
{
    public List<string> Data = new List<string>();
    public UserData() { }
}
```

Next, when you close the app, or maybe during some other action like clicking a save button use this code:

```
UserData uData = new UserData();
foreach (object i in comboBox1.Items) // Change name of ComboBox if necessary.
{
    uData.Data.Add(i.ToString());
}
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserData));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("userData.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) // Change path accordingly.
{
    xs.Serialize(fs, uData);
}
```

To read the data during app startup use this code:

```
 XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserData));
 UserData deserializedData; // This is the retrieved data. Use this after the following Using Block
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("userData.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) //Again, change the path accordingly
 {
     deserializedData = (UserData)xs.Deserialize(fs);
 }
 //Now deserializedData contains the read data.
 comboBox1.Items.Clear(); // Delete all items...
 comboBox1.Items.AddRange(deserializedData.Data.ToArray<Object>()); //...and add the retrieved items
```